# What is the pattern behind respond_to / respond_with in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a specific name to [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)? For me it looks like a view router, or a presenter router (I would name it like that) but maybe there is a better name and explication.

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with calling this a strategy pattern or a collection of template methods.

But don't try too hard to assign names to how ruby is used.  In ruby you can add and modify classes and [individual objects](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/singletonmethods.html), throw around code blocks etc., with such ease that the standard design patterns seem less pertinent after a while.

Comment: If it doesn't have a specific name, then I'll stick with Strategy. If we take Strategy and Bridge, they are actually the same pattern, except that a Strategy objectifies an algorithm, a behaviour, while Bridge is for specifying object structure. Maybe this thing will get a name if it gets more popular.

I think that it doesn't depend much on what tools the programming language provides. The design patterns seem more about a concept than of the actual implementation. So if you implement the Strategy pattern with modules or Roles with extending objects, it is still going to be the given pattern